# Please explain which execution( synchronous or asynchronous) is use in run time Asihttp method

Tags: ios, asynchronous, request, synchronous

I'm really confused about the concept of synchronous execution and asynchronous execution.
 which type of execution is use in AsiHttprequest and what is the flow work in example??
 None of the resources I've read were helpful so far. 
also explain difference between them

Comment: Why give me negative response..?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  `synchronous` request main thread gets block and control will not get back to user till that request gets execute.

In `Asynchronous` control gets back to user even if request is getting execute.

If know more about it please see this link.. 
[Asynchronous Vs. Synchronous Execution, What does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)